# History : For what technical reason(s) GNOME was forced to remove its icons from the desktop by default?

Tags: gnome, history

I'm asking a question about *GNOME* History.

I've red on few websites that *GNOME* developers where forced to remove the ability to put icons on desktop by default, for some technical reasons that I can't remember or have not understood then.

Can you explain me what happened that forced this choice to be made?

Comment: Do you have links to the websites?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://csorianognome.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/nautilus-desktop-plans/) by any chance? The related technical discussion is [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158) (but it may not be all that enlightening).

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't have them in mind anymore. But if you are using GNOME, you can notice that you can't put icon on the desktop itself to launch your applications or for shortcuts of documents. I red maybe some Internet website such as the one you found, but yes : I didn't understood clearly what happened and if someone is able to provide a clear explanation I would enjoy to read it. For simple knowledge. I'm just curious.